# How to Call document.ready(function()) routines during a .load() Call

Tags: jquery

I have the following line in my document.ready() section, i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // initialize scrollable
    $("#browsable").scrollable();
});
```

This all works fine at initial page start-up, which is my "Home" menu option. The problem is, I have a side menu where the user clicks on an option, which then loads my html page in using jQuery .load(), based on the option selected, such as "About Us".

But when the user clicks back on the "Home" menu option, after just leaving the "About Us" page, my `$("#browsable").scrollable();` is not being initialized/called again, which causes issues with my carousel.

Using this .load() call, how can I get it to redo initialization using `$("#browsable").scrollable();` call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the jQuery Documentation, you can set a call back in the load call, like this...

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
    $("#browsable").scrollable();
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [live method](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Or use the callback function of the load function to initialize the scrollable plug-in on the loaded content, as Sohnee suggests.